# apk build by corona is not install in device

Tags: android, build, coronasdk

I am new with corona developing.

I am creating a new project and them build as android apk target 2.2.

It will make build successfully bt if i run this build on my device it shows "not installed".

I am using trial version of corona is this make a problem?

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Did you made the device accept installs of non-signed apps?

Comment: Hi. Did you even find a solution? I'm having the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

When I had a similar problem, it was because the architecture on my device wasn't ARMv7.

The developers behind Corona have made these points regarding Android deployment:

> - You do not need to install the Android SDK. However, you will need to install the x86 (32-bit) version of the Java 6 Development Kit if you're using Windows. Corona does not support JDK7. See Java Development Kit Setup for details.
> - The Android build process generates a standard .apk file. You can build and test apps on Android devices without creating a Google developer account, but you will need an account if you wish to publish to the Google Play marketplace. The current price of the program is $25, mandated and managed by Google.
> - **We only support Android devices that run Android 2.2 or higher with an ARMv7 processor. This can create some confusion because ARM processors are identified by both a family and an architecture. Family names do not have a "v" in them. For instance, the ARM7 processor is actually a ARMv3 architecture, and ARM11 is a ARMv6 architecture. See this guide to help identify the various processors.**

Source: http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/androidBuild/index.html (worth a read if you haven't seen it already)

Answer (score 0):

Download some app to your device like app manager or Es File Explorer(

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5lc3Ryb25ncy5hbmRyb2lkLnBvcCJd)

And open that app, select your .apk file, and there u can install it.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Amm Thanks for your answer but actually the problem is my apk which is build properly. but not installed in device. And Corona is the reason for that.

Comment: I think your probalme is coming by you need to instal 1st that apk file. For that u need to open in some file manager.(download that, put your apk to device, open that app select your .apk file and install it.)

Answer (score 0):

I find the simplest way is to just attach the .apk file to an e-mail and open the attachment in Gmail on the phone.

You can build for Android using the Trial version of Corona. Just use the default key. (I might have enabled a setting under Apps to allow installing apps from outside Google Play, I don't remember.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to install my app via a adb console with my phone's USB debugging turned on for it to work.

The command was:

```
[path to adb.exe] install -r [path to apk file]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before so I will share you my experience.

It could be one of two problems:

1. Your device isn't ARMv7.  That means it needs to be 2.2 or higher.  I would recommend using Android 4.0 or higher for a test device, that's just my opinion though.
2. You could have a syntax error or you could be requiring a document that doesn't exist.  In some rare instances Corona doesn't detect the error until it's on the device.  To see what the error is, run `adb logcat`.

Let me know if this works for you :)